# For what values of x,the following matrix is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
x &   1   & 2x\\
0 &  x-1 &  0\\
1  &  3 &   x^2+3\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
By finding the det i get the answer
$$\det A =x^4-x^3+x^2-x$$
But i still dont know what is the $x$ value to make the matrix to be invertible

Comment: Hint: $\det A = x^3 (x-1) + x(x-1) = x(x-1)(x^2 + 1)$, and matrix invertible iff $\det \ne 0$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: A matrix is invertible if and only if it's determinant is non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix would be invertible at those values where the determinant of the matrix is not zero. So solving for $x$ we get values of $x$ as $0$, $1$, $i$ and $-i$ where the determinant would be zero. Hence excluding these points the matrix would invertible on all the other points.

Comment: Can i know how to get the i values? From solving the x values, i could only get 0 and 1

Comment: Actually if you are talking about real numbers then 0 and 1 would be your answer.But if you consider complex numbers too you'll get an equation $x^2 +1 =0$ which gives you other two complex values of x.

Answer (score 1):

Factor the determinant. It is most easy expanding it along the second row:
\begin{align}
\begin{vmatrix}x&1&2x\\0&x-1&0\\1&3&x^2+3\end{vmatrix}&=(x-1)\begin{vmatrix}x&2x\\1&x^2+3\end{vmatrix}\\
&=x(x-1)\begin{vmatrix}1&2\\1&x^2+3\end{vmatrix}&&\text{by linearity}\\
&=x(x-1)(x^2+1).
\end{align}
This the matrix is not invertible if and only if $\;x=0,\:1$ or$\;\pm i\;$ (if you work with matrices with coefficients in $\mathbf C$).

Comment: The last expression has $(x-1)$ and not $(x-)$ right? That is a typo.

Comment: Yes. One always should re-read oneself. Thanks for pointing the typo!

Comment: Now there is an extra parenthesis in the 2nd to last expression. :-)

Comment: Fixed! Not sure I haven't added some extra typo ;o)